# multipage API request with for loop doesn't get data next pages

Tags: python, api, for-loop

I try to get all data from a multipage API with a for loop.

```
# API request multipage
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64, pandas as pd, json

page_num=0

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'X-Customer-Id':'1234',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'123456789'
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    
   'page': page_num,
    'size':100,
   
})

try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('url')
        for page_num in range(2):
            conn.request("GET", "/stock/v1/?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
            response = conn.getresponse()
            rawdata = response.read()
            print(rawdata)
            conn.close()
            page_num =+1
except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

This code gives 2 times the data of the fist page in stead of the data of page 0 and page 1.

auto get next page doesn't work properly

Comment: You are passing the same `params` every time. Because `params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'page': page_num, 'size':100,})` just sets that value at a single point in time. You need to move that bit of code inside the `for` loop so that `params` gets a new value on each iteration of the loop

Comment: Where would you suggest to insert the params definition

Comment: Tryed insert params definition after for loop condition and it worked thanks a lot